# intuition for definition of immersions

Tags: differential-geometry

A smooth map $f: M \to N$ is said to be an immersion if $df_p$ is injective for all $p\in M$.I have a hard time in interpreting the meaning of injectivity in this definition.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Immersions can have self-intersection.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown:sorry.i have edited the question

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown:could you give me a hint

Comment: An immersion is a local embedding.  So, every point on $M$ has a neighborhood such that $f$ restricted to that neighborhood is an embedding.  This is nice because the structure of $M$ as a manifold is preserved under this map, at least locally.  This means $M$ wasn't squished into $N$ in a terrible way.

Comment: @Joe Johnson:thanks for your answer,but this still doesn't answers my question.I have asked the need for $df_p$ to be injective

Comment: My point about preserving differential structure is why it needs to be injective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the key insight about immersions comes from the *Rank Theorem*: If $f: M\to N$ is an immersion, then for each $p\in M$ there are coordinates $(x^1,\dots,x^m)$ on a neighborhood of $p$ and coordinates $(y^1,\dots,y^m,y^{m+1},\dots,y^n)$ on a neighborhood of $f(p)$ such that the local coordinate representation of $f$ is given by
$$
f(x^1,\dots,x^m) = (x^1,\dots,x^m,0,\dots,0).\tag{$\ast$}
$$
In other words, up to a change of coordinates, an immersion looks locally like the natural inclusion of $\mathbb R^m$ into $\mathbb R^n$.

On the other hand, any map that has a representation in local coordinates as inclusion of a linear subspace automatically has injective differential. So the real reason for the definition is this: *a smooth map has injective differential everywhere if and only if in a neighborhood of each point it has a coordinate representation which is inclusion of a linear subspace.*

Comment: :thanks a lot for such great answer sir.

Comment: :can we say that the consideration of injection ensures that rank of the derivative map remains same as dim ($T_p(M)$=dim(M) .for example,for immersion of a klein bottle into $\mathbb R^3$,at the circle of self-intersection,each tangent space at f(p) still retains it's two dimensional character because of condition of injectivity of derivative map.if we were to map the klein bottel to $\mathbb R^3$ using constant map,that would not be an immersion

Comment: If the immersion is not injective (like the typical immersion of the Klein bottle that you see pictures of), then the "tangent space to the image" doesn't make any sense because the image might not be a manifold. But for each point in the _domain_ (in this case an abstract Klein bottle), the image of the tangent space will be a two-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^3$.  But if different points in the domain map to the same point in $\mathbb R^3$, you'll get different two-dimensional subspaces there.

Comment: :thanks for your view sir.I understand that image might not be a manifold ,i am saying that  for each point in the domain (in this case an abstract Klein bottle), the image of the tangent space will be a two-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^3$.Moreover ,i can now add the condition of injectivity on F and hence F becomes a bijection from M to F(M),which can be used to define topology on F(M) and under this F,M is diffeomorphic to F(M) and thus we have immersed submanifolds.